# is it possible to add interceptor for fetch in google chrome extension

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension, fetch, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am using fetch to do http request in google chrome extension v3, and I want to add header for each request and do the relogin when the auth token is invalid in the http response. is it possible to add interceptor for fetch, I am searching from internet and found the axios lib could do this but the axios lib did not compatible with the google chrome extension, how to add interceptor to the fetch api?

Comment: Hi, I usually solve this by 2 different ways, depending on my situation: 1. use cookie to hold the token. 2. Write custom wrapper method that adds the header with each request. Not really sure if this is best practice tho

Comment: I also think about this solution, but it seems not perfect, I want a better way to do this.@TDiblik

Comment: Hey, just checking, did you solve it? To bo honest, I'm really interested if you found a better way to do this kind of thing :)

Comment: I did not solved this problem.@TDiblik

Comment: Hi, just remembered about this question, I found a [really nice blog post from logrocket](https://blog.logrocket.com/intercepting-javascript-fetch-api-requests-responses/), that achieves fetch interception (if you're still having this issue).